# Normal naming convention for a public static variable in a class?

Tags: c#

My code looks like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static PhrasesPage phrasesPage;
```

Here's the class definition:

```
public partial class PhrasesPage
```

Is the variable name normally written as phrasesPage or PhrasesPage?

Comment: It is "usual" to case publicly visible members as PascalCase, so `PhrasesPage`, but that's just common practice, not a requirement.

Comment: Does that not make it confusing as I thought class names like PhrasesPage would always use a first character uppercase?

Comment: There's plenty more [reading in the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines), and specifically here for [Type Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-fields)

Comment: i'd say `PhrasesPage` and in the msdn docs for naming convention, they say one shouldn't just name a static variable like it's class

Comment: I added in the class definition to the question.  Not sure if it makes things more clear but would appreciate comments.  Thanks

Comment: Using case to name a member the same name as its type is not really making it more understandable as you're just inventing a "convention". You should name the field in a way that tries to explain its purpose, rather than relying on the name of its own type. That would be like calling a Human "human" instead of "John".

Comment: Get a resharper and see for yourself

Comment: If you care about convention, you should not have a public field period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global variable or field I would almost always start uppercase:

```
public int MyInt;
```

And lowercase if its a local variable:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    int myInt;
}
```

For more detailed guidelines: [MS guidelines for naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx)

So for a public static variable you would use [PascalCase](http://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase)

---

**Note -- Don't name a variable the same as its type:**

```
public static PhrasesPage PhrasesPage
```

Find a descriptive name instead

Comment: I added in the class definition to the question.  Does that change things at all. Thank you

Comment: The OP explicitly asks for  **public static fields**, which are indeed not well documented

Comment: @CasparKleijne static does not change anything in terms of naming as far as I know

Comment: @Alan That doesn't change anything. Just start uppercase :)

Comment: Having underscores for private fields is a vb.net (unofficial) convention and should not be used in C#

Comment: @CodingYoshi Ah, been using that for so long now... normal in most companies too.... but ill get rid of it :)

Comment: Normal in most companies does not mean convention. The convention actually discourages that.

Comment: @CodingYoshi The ms guidelines file is 90 pages long and often they don't follow their own rules. I recommend no one to strictly follow that ruleset but instead agree with their team on the rules that make sense

Comment: Teams can have agreed upon rules but the question is about guidelines and not `what your team uses`. Guidelines by MS in this case. Just because MS does not follow it, does not mean it is no longer a guideline.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yeah thats why I edited it... My point is, the guidelines are 90 pages and what rules are from my team and what rules are from ms is not something I think about daily so I put it in there....

Answer (score 0):

According to the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members):

> public or protected instance fields are not allowed by the member design guidelines.
>
> DO use PascalCasing [I think this is a typo and should be camel case] in field names.
>
> ✓ DO name fields using a noun, noun phrase, or adjective.
>
> X DO NOT use a prefix for field names.

Those are guidelines so if you still want to go ahead and have a public field, use PascalCasing so in your case it would be `PhrasesPage`. Now whether that's a good name it or not is your decision.